# how to restrict access of the subscribers to the published messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

i have four trucks connected to a mqtt broker, and I have four Apps/devices. the trucks publishes messages and the Apps subscribe to these message

is there any way to restrict the access of the devices to the message published by the trucks? in another words, lets assume truck1 publishes the following messages (truck1_msg1, truck1_msg2, truck1_msg) I want App1 able to subscribe and listen to the messages from truck1 only and never be able to subscribe and see any other messages published by other trucks. is it possible? would you please let me how can I do it?

**note**: all the trucks and the Apps are connected to the same broker, and lets assume it is Mosquitto

Answer (score 2):

Most MQTT brokers support topic level ACLs for a given user so assuming each truck publishes messages to a distinct topic (or topic prefix as ACLs tend to support wild cards) and each truck and app has it's own user you should be able to arrange any segregation of access you need.

Each broker have different mechanisms for managing these ACLs, for example here are the details for mosquitto.

The documentation for mosquitto's ACL format can be found in it's man page here: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

You add an ACL file to the mosquitto.conf with the `acl_file` option:

```
acl_file /path/to/acl/file
```

The ACL file format looks like this:

```
user <username>
topic [read|write|readwrite] <topic>
```

You can have multiple topic lines per user.

Details of how to enable user authentication is also in the man page.

Comment: Any particular reason for the down vote, this answers the question?